# C++ not printing as expected with my own string copy function

Tags: c++, string, strcpy

sorry for another string copy question.. but I really can't find the reason why in my code, strTo can be printed, but strFinal can't in neither way.

```
cout << strTo << endl;

cout << strFinal << endl;
while (*strFinal != '\0') {
    cout << *strFinal++;
}
```

Appreciated if someone can point it out where I misunderstood about pointers and arrays! Thanks!

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

char *str_copy (const char *strFrom, char *strTo) 
{
    while (*strFrom != '\0') {
        *strTo++ = *strFrom++;
    }
    *strTo = '\0';
    return strTo;
}

int main()
{
    char strFrom[]="abc123";
    char strTo[10];
    char *strFinal = str_copy(strFrom, strTo);

    cout << strTo << endl;

    cout << strFinal << endl;
    while (*strFinal != '\0') {
        cout << *strFinal++;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Additional Question:

I don't know the reason when I put the code in main function like this:

```
char strFrom[]="abc123";
char strTo[10];
strTo = str_copy(strFrom, strTo);
```

Then complier said:

> main.cpp:18: error: array type 'char [10]' is not assignable
>       strTo = str_copy(strFrom, strTo);
>       ~~~~~ ^

How should I correct in this way? Thanks!

Comment: You might want to write `cout << *(strFinal++);` to be safe, I don't remember if `++` takes precedence over `*`.  Also, I could be wrong, but `*strTo++ = *strFrom++;` might be undefined behavior or otherwise not working as you are expecting, perhaps change it to do the increments on the next two lines and see if that works.

Comment: hint - where does your strTo point to after str_copy?

Comment: Find out how to use the debugger on your system, then you will be able to figure this sort of thing out much more quickly.

Comment: ©AlanStokes yes, I need to learn about GDB, thanks for suggestions!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function returns a pointer to the terminating zero.

```
char *str_copy (const char *strFrom, char *strTo) 
{
    //...
    *strTo = '\0';
    return strTo;
}
```

Change it the following way

```
char *str_copy (const char *strFrom, char *strTo) 
{
    char *p = strTo;
    while ( *p++ = *strFrom++ );

    return strTo;
}
```

Also I would declare it the same way as standard C function `strcpy` is declared

```
char *str_copy( char *strTo, const char *strFrom );
```

As for your additional question then you may not assign a pointer or even other array to an array. So the compiler issues the error.

Arrays have no the assignment operator. You can only copy their elements.
Otherwise use standard class `std::array`.

Answer (score 1):

After returning from `str_copy` you strTo does not point to the beginning of your copied string. In `main` `strTo` is ok, because it was passed by value (address of pointer after returning from `str_copy` is not changed even though you were using `strTo++`). But returned value of `strFinal` points to last character of copied string - `'\0'`.

For second part - char[10] has unchangeable addres, so you can't assign anything to variable of this type, like you tried in `strTo = str_copy(...);`.

Comment: ur explaination makes me much more clear now! thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Your second question : you are trying to assing char[10] with char* which is not possible

```
&strTo[0] = str_copy(strFrom, strTo);
```

But it's not usefull since the copy is done inside

Answer (score 0):

In ur code, after calling str_copy() function:

```
char *strFinal = str_copy(strFrom, strTo);
```

`strFinal` points to the '\0', which is at the end of "abc123".

`strTo` in main() function can display correctly, because it is not THE SAME `strTo`
 in str_copy() function, but points to strTo[10]. `strTo` in str_copy() still points to the terminating zero.